# Why does Laton devote his life to figure out uploading his conciousness to shell beings when other Edenists already do this?

Tags: nights-dawn-trilogy

**DISCLAIMER: For those of you who have not read the Nights Dawn trilogy then there are massive spoilers in this question.**

In the first book we are introduced to the character Laton, a former Edenist and mad scientist of sorts who was hiding on the planet Lalonde.  In the dialogue where Laton meets Quinn Dexter he explains that for the last 30 years he had been perfecting a method to use the Edenist affinity to "upload" his mind into other bodies to not only achieve immortality, but so that he could create entire armies of himself.

He draws the paralels to the Edenist ability to upload their thought patterns and memories into their habitats before they die so they live on in the collective.  Later in the series of course it is realized that the thought patterns and memories do not equate to the human soul which is a seperate entity of itself.

In the second and third books however we actually see the Edenists doing pretty much exactly what Laton described in the first book.  In the second book, Ione uploads her memories and thought patterns into multiple Serjeant constructs to protect Joshua on his mission to retrieve the Alchemist.  These Serjeants had no other identity and were in fact multiple copies of Ione, limited though by the smaller neural capacity of the beings.

Another example in the second book was Rubra (who was not an Edenist), the chairman of Magellan Corp uploading himself into the neural strata of the Valisk habitat and essentially subjugating its identity making Valisk and Rubra become one in the same.

In the third book, the Mortonridge Liberation campaign is carried out by Serjeant constructs that had the memories and thought patterns of long deceased Edenist volunteers that willingly did this.

Yet another example in the third book is Euru uploading himself tens of times into various labrotory neural structures to test the Anti-Memory weapon.

This seems like a giant plot hole to me.  I imagine if it was this easy for Edenists to do this later in the books then Laton wouldn't have spent the better part of his life figuring out how to do the same thing.

Did I miss some important explanation about this somewhere in the series?  Is what Laton was attempting something different and I just misunderstood?

Answer (score 4):

It's been a while since I read the books, but I think Laton wanted to be able to copy his mind onto other humans, instead of artificial constructs. Once he is possessed, killed, and goes on to possess another person -and a habitat, if I recall correctly - he realizes that there is vastly more to experience by allowing himself to die, than if he tries to become "immortal".

Comment: I must have missed this but that you brought it up it certainly fits the plot.  I do remember now him explaining how he discovered how to rewire the human brain where it could run parallel cognitive identities by studying habitat neural structures.  Thanks for the answer!  I love these books so far and am glad that I am not the only one who has read them.